# CLR Integration function that will take an Image/Varbinary value as input

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr, varbinarymax

I am trying to create a CLR integration function in SQL Server 2008 R2 which will read a `Image/Varbinary` value and return a `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlString ConvertByteArrToString(SqlBinary arrByte)
```

And in SQL Server -

```
create function ReadAsString(@varData varbinary(max))
returns nvarchar(max)
as
    external name CLRFunctions.[CLRFunctions.FormatUtilities].ConvertByteArrToString
```

But, when I try to create above function, I get this error:

> Msg 6552, Level 16, State 3, Procedure ReadAsString, Line 1
>   ALTER FUNCTION for "ReadAsString" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for parameter "@varData" do not match.

Can someone suggest what should be the correct CLR match for SQL Server `Image/Varbinary(MAX)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4764583/73226

Answer (score 0):

The technical answer to the Question as asked is: `SqlBytes` maps to `VARBINARY(MAX)` when using the Visual Studio deployment option (and there is no mapping to `IMAGE` which is deprecated and shouldn't be used). But that is for older versions of Visual Studio and SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools). The more recent versions now map `SqlString` and `SqlChars` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, and `SqlBinary` and `SqlBytes` to `VARBINARY(MAX)`. Some additional details are provided in this answer: [CLR UDF returning Varbinary(MAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840552/clr-udf-returning-varbinarymax/4764583#4764583) .

*HOWEVER*, given that you are using SQL Server 2008 R2, this SQLCLR function doesn't even need to be created in the first place since it is functionality built into the [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx) built-in function:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 0x1234ABCD);    -- 㐒춫
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 0x1234ABCD, 0); -- 㐒춫
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 0x1234ABCD, 1); -- 0x1234ABCD
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 0x1234ABCD, 2); -- 1234ABCD
```