# Character Problem When Converting image Data Type to String in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm runing query like this:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(IDAT as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))
```

IDAT column type is the "image", query executing successful but some Turkish characters are 'Ã§aÄŸdaÅŸ' like this. it should be 'çağdaş'.
I tried this :

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(IDAT as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS
```

Nothing changed. Does anyone have an idea for this situation?

Comment: 'Ã§aÄŸdaÅŸ' is 9 symbols, while 'çağdaş' is only 6. What is the size of the data in IDAT? Post is as hex value. Do you know the encoding used for the data stored there?

Comment: Value before casting varchar : 0x68C3BC736579696E20616C692076656C69206E6F746C617220C59F65726D696E2061C49F72C4B120C3B66BC3BC7A20C3A761C49F6461C59F i dont know encoding using for this data.

Comment: SQL Server already supports Unicode. *Don't* store text as binary, you don't need it

Comment: The Unicode types are `nchar` and `nvarchar`. Don't use `varchar` unless you can *ensure* the text matches the collation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This binary value `0x68C3BC736579696E20616C692076656C69206E6F746C617220C59F65726D696E2061C49F72C4B120C3B66BC3BC7A20C3A761C49F6461C59F` is UTF-8 encoded, which converted to text is `hüseyin ali veli notlar şermin ağrı öküz çağdaş`. Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8 until 2019, so you must decode it yourself. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168055/convert-text-value-in-sql-server-from-utf8-to-iso-8859-1) explains how to do it.

If you can change the application and store the value in UTF-16 you will be able to cast it to `NVARCHAR` directly (or just store the data as text).

Comment: The answer to that question is really bad. A simple SQLCLR UDF that with just a single call `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputBytes.Value)` would be faster and far more likely to be correct. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840552/clr-udf-returning-varbinarymax) shows the reverse, generating UTF8 bytes from a string.

Comment: Yes, if CLR is an option, it will be much better option. But still, changes in the application would be better. If this text must be available as UTF-8 in the database (why?!) and converted to text in the database (again, why?), then the application could simply store it twice :)

Comment: Actually, My only interest is converting this data type to the right string. in this case, @AndreyNikolov solution is successful worked.